# Can a unique list accept lower and uppercase entries

Tags: python, list, unique

My script logs information about all the unique file types in a directory and subdirectory. In the process of creating a unique list of file extensions the current code considers that jpg, Jpg and JPG are the same so it only includes one of them in the List. How can I include all three or more variances?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SourceDIR, topdown=False):
    for fl in files:
        currentFile=os.path.join(root, fl)
        ext=fl[fl.rfind('.')+1:]
        if ext!='':
            if DirLimiter in currentFile:
                List.append(currentFile)
                directory1=os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(currentFile[:currentFile.rfind(DirLimiter)]))
                directory2=(currentFile[len(SourceDIR):currentFile.rfind('\\'+directory1+DirLimiter)])
                directory=directory2+'\\'+directory1
                if directory not in dirList:
                    dirCount+=1
                    dirList.append(directory)


        if ext not in extList:
          extList.append(ext)
```

The full script is in this question on stackexchange: [Recurse through directories and log files by file type in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618238/recurse-through-directories-and-log-files-by-file-type-in-python)

Thanks to JennaK on further investigation I found the input in the jpg report actually had JPG and jpg in the file as below.

```
> 44;X:\scratch\project\Input\Foreshore and Jetties Package
> 3\487679 - Jetty\IMG_1630.JPG;3755267
> 45;X:\scratch\project\Input\Foreshore and Jetties Package
> 3\487679 - Jetty\IMG_1633.JPG;2447135
> 1;X:\scratch\project\Input\649701 - Hill
> Close\2263.jpg;405328 2;X:\scratch\project\Input\649701 - Hill Close\2264.jpg;372770
```

so it first got details of all the JPG files then the jpg files and put them in a single report which is actually more convenient than having 2 reports. I guess I programmed better than I thought :-)

Comment: Do you really need adding those to the list? I mean maybe checking with string after "uppercase" function will solve your problem?

Comment: `ext not in extList` already is a case-sensitive comparison. If your code does not work, the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @JanneKarila -you are correct. I just rechecked the extList and it had all case versions. I am trying to trace the issue later on in the code and will update my answer shortly to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, for `list`, the `in` operator checks for equality, and strings are only equal to one another when they use the same case.

You could use a set here, and store all `directory.lower()` values in it. Sets are (a lot) faster for membership testing as lists as well:

```
directories = set()
extensions = set()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SourceDIR, topdown=False):
    # ...
        # no need to use `directory.lower() in directories`, just update the set:
        directories.add(directory.lower())

    # ...
    extensions.add(ext.lower())
```

The `dirCount` variable is easily derived later on:

```
dirCount = len(directories)
```

You also want to look into the functions provided by [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) some more, in particular the `os.path.splitext()`, `os.path.relpath()` and `os.path.join()` functions.

Your file handling in the loop can be simplified a lot; a:

```
for fl in files:
    filename = os.path.join(root, fl)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext:
       List.append(filename)
       directory = os.path.relpath(filename, SourceDir)
       directories.add(directory.lower())
       extensions.add(ext)
```

Note that I use **just** `os.path.relpath()` here; your `os.path.basename()` and `os.path.normpath()` dance plus delimiters, etc. was needlessly complicated.

Now, reading between the lines, it seems that you only want to consider *extensions* to be equal whatever the case of *just that part*.

In that case, build yourself a new filename from the result of `os.path.splitext()`:

```
base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
normalized_filename = base + ext.lower()
```

Now `normalized_filename` is the filename with the extension lowered, so you can use that value in the sets as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I will take these changes on board. I found that the issue was really a non issue as per my edits to the question.

Comment: Was my answer of any help at all figuring this out? Your code still had issues with needless `.normpath()` and `.basename()` calls, have I been able to figure those out?

Comment: I haven't had time to improve the code with your suggestions yet -it maybe bad but still works. Thank you for your input.